# Looping, counting, and the setInterval method

Tags: javascript, function, loops

1) Would this construct technique work?  Or would it need to have this.start()?

2)Would the index reset at any point?

```
var imageRotate = new tRotate();
window.tRotate = function(){
__construct();

this.images = new Array();
this.index = 0;



this.__construct = function(){
  tRotate.start();
  // Do other things
}
this.start = function(){
    // yadadaa
    this.interval = setInterval("this.next()",500);
}
this.pause = function(){
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
this.last = function(){
    --index;
}
this.next = function(){
    ++index;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Function expressions are evaluated in order just like any other expressions. So your call to `__construct()` and `new tRotate()` will fail. Either call it at the end:

```
tRotate = function () {
    this.__construct = function () {/* ... */}
    /* ... */


    this.__construct();
}
imageRotate = new tRotate();
```

or use function declarations instead of expressions:

```
imageRotate = new tRotate();
function tRotate () {
    __construct();

   function __construct() {/* ... */}

   /* ... */
}
```

2) The `index` can be reset if you manually reset it:

```
imageRotate.index = 0;
```

as long as you don't touch it, it won't be reset.

**update**: I just realised, several more things to comment on:

1) In javascript, `index` does not refer to `this.index`. So you need to change your methods to:

```
this.next = function () {
    this.index ++;
}
```

2) In javascript, `this` does not necessarily refer to the object the method belongs to. Specifically, for functions executed by `setInterval`, `this` refers to the `window` object. So you need to capture `this` in a closure. There are several ways to do this:

```
function tRotate () {
    var self = this; // self refers to the correct 'this'

    this.start = function () {
        self.interval = setInterval(self.next,500);
             /* note: you need to pass a reference here, a string
              *       won't work because in the context of the
              *       window object the variable self is undefined
              */
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

or

```
function tRotate () {
    function makeStartMethod (self) {
        self.interval = setInterval(self.next,500);
    }
    this.start = makeStartMethod(this);

    /* ... */
}
```